# Select element in jQuery by using class names

Tags: jquery, class

I want to select an element that has all the specified classes. Every time, class names are different.

For ex.

If specified classes are: A and B
Then element which has classes A, B, C, D or A, B should get selected.
But element which has only class A or B, should not be selected.

Comment: then use the selector `$('.A.B')`

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your help.